# Call Ruby 1.8 script from Ruby 2.0 script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, ruby-2.0, ruby-1.8

I'm not sure if this belongs here or somewhere else (SuperUser?) but anyway:

I've got two Ruby scripts, one which requires Ruby 2.0 (A) and another which requires 1.8 (B). A needs to call B with a forked processes. A is something like this:

```
require "fileutils"
require "json"

...

`name_of_B`
```

B is an executable script with a shebang, starting like this:

```
#!/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby
require 'rubygems'
require 'json'

...
```

I use `RVM` to manage my Ruby versions:

```
> rvm list
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.8.7-p374 [ i686 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p448 [ x86_64 ]
=* ruby-2.0.0-p247 [ x86_64 ]
```

I run A with:

```
> ruby name_of_A
```

but end up with:

```
/Users/jacobevelyn/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/json-1.8.1/lib/json/ext/parser.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [i686-darwin12.5.0]
```

Any thoughts on what I can do? I don't know a whole lot about gems but it appears that B tries to look at gems installed under Ruby 2.0, rather than 1.8. (Yes, I've run `gem install json` under 1.8 already.) Obviously the scripts are more complicated than they appear here and absolutely cannot be ported or combined (this doesn't mean I don't *want* to, it means I *can't* for my use case), otherwise I would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change the shebang to:

```
#!/Users/user_name/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p374/ruby
```

it will not only use that ruby but also its gems.

in case you use bundler (Gemfile) you might also need to wrap the command invocation in:

```
Bundler.with_clean_env do
  ...
end
```

which will reset loaded bundler environment

Comment: The shebang here didn't seem to work quite right, but if A calls B with `/Users/user_name/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.8.7-p374/ruby name_of_B` it does. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Call:

```
result = `\path\to\ruby_1_8 \path\to\ruby_1_8_script.rb`
```

This will use the correct ruby binary to execute the script that expects it.  The result is saved into the var.

---

You can call `which ruby` to find the version of the ruby in your current directory.  Go to your project / source dir and call it to see the version (presumably Ruby 2) that you're using for the main app.  Then, go to your old project / repo (associated with the 1.8 script) and run it again.  Hopefully that will show you the path to Ruby 1.8.  If not, try it from root (`/`).  Or use RVM to confidently switch to Ruby 1.8 and then call it there to get the path.

---

I've never used RVM much.  If it is confused, and filters things through the wrong gem set, etc, then you may need instead to switch to [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).  Also, you may need to use its own functions to display the true path to the Ruby 1.8 binary (i.e. maybe it messes with `which`?)  Again, I don't RVM.

Comment: This still doesn't work, unfortunately. I'm running `/Users/user_name/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby name_of_B` and getting the same error. And I've tried `rvm use 1.8 ; name_of_B ; rvm use 2.0` but then I get: "RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work." and then the segfault again.

Comment: Does that command work outside of Ruby 2.0?  Like if you call it from the command line?

Comment: RVM won't work inside Ruby 2.0 because RVM is loaded through your shell startup script.  You could try sourcing that file (`.bashrc`?) but I've never done that before.